# How to pass IOptions through Dependency injection to another Project

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a WebApplication targetting .net core.
I have also created a Class Library targetting .net core as well.

I am creating a Users Repository following this Dapper tutorial [Here](http://www.talkingdotnet.com/use-dapper-orm-with-asp-net-core/)

It would be nice to be able to provide the option that was injected in start up of the WebApplication into the project that will be the data access layer.

Here is the code for the Users Repository in a separate project.

```
class UsersRepository
    {
        private readonly MyOptions _options;
        private string connectionString;
        public UsersRepository(IOptions iopt/// insert Option here )
        {
            _options = iopt.Value;
            connectionString = _options.connString;
        }

        public IDbConnection Connection
        {
            get
            {
                return new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            }
        }
```

The WebApplication Project Startup looks as follows.

```
public class Startup
   {

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddOptions();

        services.Configure<MyOptions>(Configuration);

        services.AddMvc();
    }
```

and of course `MyOptions` is a class in the web application that has only one property `connString`

Comment: And what is stopping you from doing that? have the other project reference options extension library and use the interface then register the repository with the composition root.

Comment: @Nkosi those were in fact words you said :P

Comment: I don't quite understand your last comment. Did you remove a previous comment that would put that last one into context?

Comment: @Nkosi it was a joke meaning I didn't quite understand what you are saying. A lot of those terms I am unfamiliar with. I'm guessing you are saying make a new project with only the options, and reference it in both projects, but the interface, register, composition root words I don't understand what to do to accomplish those three.

Comment: Given you were referring to dependency injection I figured you knew the terms well enoigh. Ok IOptions is part of the Options extension library of asp.net-core. It's in the documentation. You want your other project to reference the abstractions library, which will give you access to the IOptions interface so you can use it. In the ConfigureServices method, which is your configuration/composition root you would register your repository with the service collection which would allow the options to be injected into your business class

Comment: If you want share classes with multiple projects, you need to break them out of the web application project, since your libraries can't reference the application, as it causes a circular dependencies (Library depends on App, App on Library) and would be a bad practice anyway, even if it worked

Answer (score 6):

One possible design is to make a new interface for your repository configuration inside your class library, and have your MyOptions type implement that interface.

For example, in your class library you can do the following:

```
public interface IRepositoryConfig
{
    string ConnectionString { get; }
}

public class UserRepository
{
    public UserRepository(IRepositoryConfig config)
    {
       // setup
    }
}
```

And in your WebAPI Startup class you can wire this up as follows:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddOptions();

    services.Configure<MyOptions>(Configuration);

    services.AddMvc();

    services.AddScoped<IRepositoryConfig>(s =>
        s.GetService<IOptions<MyOptions>>().Value
    );

    services.AddScoped<UserRepository>();
}
```

Doing this will allow you to use the Asp.Net Core configuration/options framework without having to reference any Asp.Net DLLs in your class library directly.

Comment: Wish I'd found this hours ago. This is a great way to inject options in to a library too.